# Snowflake subquery to simulate COUNTIF

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following query why I"m attempting to simulate a `COUNTIF` across two tables:

```
WITH Range__A1_A4 (val) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10
), NFL (SEASON, TEAM, WINS) AS (
    SELECT 2010, 'KC', 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2011, 'GB', 11
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN NFL.WINS>R.val THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Range__A1_A4 R) ct,
    *
FROM NFL;
```

From this I get the following error:

> Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

What's wrong with this query and what would be the proper way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
WITH Range__A1_A4 (val) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (1),
        (2),
        (8),
        (10)
), NFL (SEASON, TEAM, WINS) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (2010, 'KC', 10),
        (2011, 'GB', 11)
)
SELECT 
    n.*,
    SUM(iff( n.wins > r.val, 1, 0)) as ct_a,
    count_if(n.wins > r.val) as ct_b
FROM NFL AS n
JOIN Range__A1_A4 AS r
group by 1,2,3;
```

| SEASON | TEAM | WINS | CT | CT_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2,010 | KC | 10 | 3 | 3 |
| 2,011 | GB | 11 | 4 | 4 |

Comment: yea -- is there a short-hand for doing something like `group by NFL.*` ?

Comment: by the way, what's the reason the correlated subquery doesn't work in the case where the tables are not joined?

Comment: correlated subquery support is "partial" and sometime simple sub-queries can stop working as you add "unrelated stuff" and the optimizer cannot see how to make it work

Comment: too the group by thing, not that I know..

Comment: yea it seems to work in a few other backends: https://gyazo.com/26cd47608d1bc3d7030b6b8c4f5cf163

Comment: oh for sure, it's do able. I suspect it's mostly easy to do badly (performance wise) so simple to not add a feature coverage where the user knows the shape of their data better, and can write the SQL to solve the problem.